# Linux cannot enter directory

Tags: linux, directory

I have a mailbox on my Debian server (with Dovecot). I have the problem that I can't enter a directory. Looks like there are two similar directories:

From `ls -al`

```
drwx------  6 vmail mail    4096 Nov  8 20:48 .Sent Items
drwx------  6 vmail mail    4096 Nov  8 20:33 .Sent\ Items
```

I can enter in the second directory with `cd .Sent\ Items`, but not the first one. I don't even know, how that first directory was created.

How can I get into the first one?

Kind regards

Comment: Try `cd .Sent` and hit the `TAB` key.  Or temporarily rename the one you can reach, then `cd .Sent TAB`.  Don't forget to rename other directory back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @ppovski

I renamed the first one that came with TAB, then I could the one without \ in it's name.

For others:

If you want to enter a directory which has a space in it's name, but no backslash \ before the space, you can enter it like this:

```
cd .Directory\\\ Spaced/
```

Kind regards